# Copy and paste new data from one workbook to another after all required data has been entered

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with two workbooks. One workbook (DDwb) contains a delivery docket template and the other workbook (Rwb) contains a record of completed deliveries showing only the key delivery info from the delivery docket template.

Each new delivery appears on the template on a new row between rows 14 and 27.
This template is saved as a separate file at the end of the month.  Multiple deliveries will be added over the month at different times. I'd like to catch the record of the new delivery in Rwb as it is added to the template.

In terms of the worksheet change event code, I want to copy the summary info once all the info for that delivery has been entered. For instance, cells: D14, E14, F14 and N14 contain the key summary info for the first delivery that month. I want to wait until this is all filled.

Also, I want to clean up my 'if cell value is >0' section by using the 'With' property but it gives compile errors.

How can I wait for the cells on the relevant row to be fully populated?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim DDwb As Workbook, Rwb As Workbook
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim myrow As Long

    Set DDwb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Rwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents (shared)\TEST - job and stock manager.xlsm")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D14:N27")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel In Target
            myrow = cel.Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)").Cells(myrow, 4).Value > 0 And DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)").Cells(myrow, 5).Value > 0 And DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)").Cells(myrow, 6).Value > 0 Then
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                'insert new row
                Rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Rows("4:4").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
                'customer name
                Rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Cells(4, 2) = "Customer name"
                'customer order number
                Rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Cells(4, 3) = DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)").Range("D" & Target.Row)
                'delivery qty
                Rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Cells(4, 4) = DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)").Range("E" & Target.Row)
                'description
                Rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Cells(4, 5) = DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)").Range("F" & Target.Row)
                'delivery date
                Rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Cells(4, 6) = "=TODAY()"
                'DD docket number
                Rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Cells(4, 7) = DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)").Range("L" & Target.Row)
                'delivery notes
                Rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Cells(4, 8) = DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)").Range("N" & Target.Row)
                Rwb.Save
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next cel
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: (1) You appear to be checking D, E, and F but not N; (2) you are checking if the value > 0 - does the value in each of those cells need to be a number? If not, you should check they're not blank.

Comment: @SJR thank you for highlighting that for me. I left it out because N col cells only contain notes which may or may not be filled out; waiting for those cells to have values may not always be true. I thought I would leave this part of the problem for me to work out once I had a hand with the main part of the code. Sorry, I realise now that I should have omitted a reference to N in my question. I should be checking if they aren't blank, I will update according. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'm pretty sure this Worksheet_Change is on the private *DD template (progressive)* worksheet code sheet so all references to ThisWorkbook and DDwb.Sheets("DD template (progressive)") are redundant.
- You are only transferring values from columns D, E, F, L & N so only those cells need to be populated.
- You're using the `=today()` formula but I think you want a static `Date`. You can revert this if you wish.
- It's unnecessary to Dim vars and open workbooks until you know you are actually going to need them.
- Disabling/enabling `EnableEvents` and `ScreenUpdating` within the loop is unnecessary. Disable once before the loop and re-enable after the loop is finished.
- You keep wanting to open the target workbook without ever closing it. I'll assume you want to close it between actions.
- You only want to transfer the values once so you need to gather a unique list of the rows involved; not a full list of all cells in Target.
- It's usually good idea to provide some error control.

> <sub>A full testing sandbox would require the artificial build of an external workbook so this has **not** been fully tested.</sub>

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:F, L:L, N:N"), Range("14:27")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim rw As Range
        Static dict As Object, ky As Variant

        If dict Is Nothing Then Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        dict.RemoveAll

        For Each rw In Intersect(Target, Range("D:F, L:L, N:N"), Range("14:27")).Rows
            'are there 5 values in D:F, L, N of this row?
            If Application.CountA(Intersect(Range("D:F, L:L, N:N"), Rows(rw.Row))) = 5 Then _
                dict.Item(rw.Row) = vbNullString
        Next rw

        if cbool(dict.count) then 
            'we finally know that there are values to transfer; time to open the external workbook
            dim vals As Variant, rwb As Workbook
            Set rwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents (shared)\TEST - job and stock manager.xlsm")
            For Each ky In dict.keys
               'there are 5 values in D:F, L, N of this row - insert new row
                rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Rows("4:4").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
                'collect values
                vals = Array("Customer name", Cells(ky, "D").Value, Cells(ky, "E").Value, Cells(ky, "F").Value, _
                              Date, Cells(ky, "L").Value, Cells(ky, "N").Value)
                'transfer values
                rwb.Sheets("Record of deliveries").Cells(4, 2).Resize(1, 7) = vals
            Next ky

            rwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this for me and for your notes explaining the gist of the code (it's a little too sophisticated for me to understand everything at this point) but I really appreciate it. The code does exactly what I was looking for thank you